# File upload with ember-upload, how to fill request with additional data for servicestack?

Tags: javascript, c#, rest, ember.js, servicestack

For introduction, I have problem with communication between servicestack and application written in ember.js via REST, I am using [ember-uploader](https://github.com/benefitcloud/ember-uploader) component to upload a file to service stack.

View hbs:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
{{file-upload}}
</table>
```

component in coffee script

```
  ABC.FileUploadComponent = Ember.FileField.extend(
  url: "/api/upload"
  filesDidChange: (->
    uploadUrl = @get("url")
    console.log uploadUrl
    files = @get("files")
    test = { fileName: "test" }
    uploader = Ember.Uploader.create(
        url: uploadUrl
    )

    uploader.upload(files[0],test) unless Ember.isEmpty(files)
    console.log files
    return
  ).observes("files")
)
```

component in javascript

```
ABC.FileUploadComponent = Ember.FileField.extend({
  url: "/api/upload",
  filesDidChange: (function() {
    var files, test, uploadUrl, uploader;
    uploadUrl = this.get("url");
    console.log(uploadUrl);
    files = this.get("files");
    test = {
      fileName: "test"
    };
    uploader = Ember.Uploader.create({
      url: uploadUrl,
      data: test
    });
    if (!Ember.isEmpty(files)) {
      uploader.upload(files[0], test);
    }
    console.log(files);
  }).observes("files")
});
```

My service model:

```
namespace ABC.Service.ServiceModel
{
    public class Upload
    {

        [Route("/upload")]
        public class UploadRequest : IRequiresRequestStream
        {
            public System.IO.Stream RequestStream { set; get; }

            public object FileName { set; get; }

        }

        public class UploadResponse
        {
            public int Successed { set; get; }

        }
    }
}
```

My Service Method

```
namespace ABC.Service.Service
{
    public class UploadService : ServiceBase // Service base inherites from ServiceStack.Service
    {
        public Upload.UploadResponse Post(Upload.UploadRequest request)
        {
            var req = base.Request;
            var reqThatIwant = request.FileName;

            return new Upload.UploadResponse() { Successed = 1 };
        }

    }
}
```

and here is screen from watch :

**So my question is, how I have to change the code to get data marked as "2" into Request object marked as "1" (marked on the screen)?**

[image: add watch screen shoot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Handling Raw Request Stream

When you use `IRequiresRequestStream` you're saying you want to [take over deserializing the Request](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Serialization-deserialization#reading-directly-from-the-request-stream) and access the raw input HTTP Request Body as a Stream. As a result ServiceStack wont attempt to read from the Request body and instead inject the HTTP Request stream - in this case the only Request DTO parameters it will be able to populate are those on the `/pathinfo` or `?QueryString`, e.g:

```
[Route("/upload/{FileName}")]
public class Upload : IRequiresRequestStream
{
    public Stream RequestStream { set; get; }

    public string FileName { set; get; }
}
```

#### Accessing FormData HTTP POSTs

But if the JavaScript component is sending you HTTP POST FormData (i.e. `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data`) than it's very unlikely you want to treat it like a raw Request Stream but instead access the `Request.FormData` or `Request.Files` that were posted.

### Handling File Upload examples

Based on your screenshot, the HTTP Request **Content-Type** is `multipart/form-data` which case you will most likely be able to [access any uploaded files using Request.Files](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Serialization-deserialization#uploading-files).

Some examples of accessing HTTP Uploaded Files are available in the [Live Demos](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/LiveDemos):

### [Imgur - Save uploaded files to a MemoryStream](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/Imgur/blob/0585d6e26264ac54669f26e9553901f305a70035/src/Imgur/Global.asax.cs#L47)

```
public object Post(Upload request)
{
    foreach (var uploadedFile in Request.Files
       .Where(uploadedFile => uploadedFile.ContentLength > 0))
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            uploadedFile.WriteTo(ms);
            WriteImage(ms);
        }
    }
    return HttpResult.Redirect("/");
}
```

### [Rest Files - Save to FileSystem](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/RestFiles/blob/30490766a871e01735602326623a5547d9a74725/src/RestFiles/RestFiles.ServiceInterface/FilesService.cs#L38)

```
public void Post(Files request)
{
    var targetDir = GetPath(request);

    var isExistingFile = targetDir.Exists
        && (targetDir.Attributes & FileAttributes.Directory) != FileAttributes.Directory;

    if (isExistingFile)
        throw new NotSupportedException(
        "POST only supports uploading new files. Use PUT to replace contents of an existing file");

    if (!Directory.Exists(targetDir.FullName))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(targetDir.FullName);

    foreach (var uploadedFile in base.Request.Files)
    {
        var newFilePath = Path.Combine(targetDir.FullName, uploadedFile.FileName);
        uploadedFile.SaveTo(newFilePath);
    }
}
```

### [HTTP Benchmarks - Handle multiple and .zip uploaded files](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/HttpBenchmarks/blob/master/src/BenchmarksAnalyzer.ServiceInterface/AuthenticatedServices.cs#L240)

```
public object Post(UploadTestResults request)
{
    //...
    foreach (var httpFile in base.Request.Files)
    {
        if (httpFile.FileName.ToLower().EndsWith(".zip"))
        {
            using (var zip = ZipFile.Read(httpFile.InputStream))
            {
                var zipResults = new List<TestResult>();
                foreach (var zipEntry in zip)
                {
                    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        zipEntry.Extract(ms);
                        var bytes = ms.ToArray();

                        var result = new MemoryStream(bytes).ToTestResult();
                        zipResults.Add(result);
                    }
                }
                newResults.AddRange(zipResults);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var result = httpFile.InputStream.ToTestResult();
            newResults.Add(result);
        }
    }
}
```